# Serving assets for mailer from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I have an email template which requires image, I decided to serve it through S3 bucket.

In template:

```
<%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>
```

application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://s3.mybucket.com"
```

But after template is rendered I get url like this:

"https://s3.mybucket.com/logo-1ee47e184c8a345a78d06117ad1b04f560256a5002ad5c5b798c41b1a.png"

Am I missing some steps here?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
<%= image_tag '/assets/logo.png' %>
```